# Customizing apache nginx backend errorlog to include x-forwarded-for / x-real-ip? How?

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, error-log

We run your default apache behind nginx setup.

This means that as far as the ip that shows up in the apache error logs is the nginx lan ip (eg: 192.168.0.X).

This means that the standard error log looks as follow (for a 404 error for example):

```
[Thu Nov 24 01:14:15 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.X] File does not exist: /somefile.html
```

We are piping over the 'real ip' of the client via:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
```

On the nginx side.

We would like this 'real ip' to show up in our error log.

I have done some searching and have not been able to find a way to customize the error log for apache.

Any ideas on how to get X-Real-IP to show up in the error_log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add mod rpaf to apache when apache is used behind a reverse proxy to log the real ip.

You can get it here: http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/

You still need to pass the real ip as you are doing.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. big ups!